Use external screens only on an optimus laptop with Xorg
I have an ASUS TUF A15(2023) optimus gaming laptop with Fedora 40 with the AMD built-in GPU and Nvidia discrete RTX 4070. Graphics configuration works well on Wayland: I connect to external monitors via HDMI and DP (over USB), which works well with the built-in display on or off. As far as I know, all the stuff is rendered on the integrated GPU, unless I request otherwise. I would like to have the same behaviour on Xorg. The Xorg configuration works well out of the box if all 3 displays (built-in and 2 external) are ON, however, when I close the laptop lid and thus switch off the built-in display, the external displays become extremely laggy (1 fps or so).
I've heard about the 1 fps but in such a case on Xorg, but the info about it is quite old. Can I have good behaviour on Xorg with some proper configuration, or is the bug still there and I can't use the integrated GPU by default on Xorg with built-in display off?
I've tried generating xorg.conf with the examples from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME#Reverse_PRIME and https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.21/README/primerenderoffload.html but they result in an inability to log in into Xorg session.

Adding -fakescreenfps 600 to /bin/Xorg seems to fix the problem, at least on the shallow level. Only-external screens in Xorg work nicely now, vsynctester.com gives nice, stable almost 60 Hz (unlike on Wayland...).
